# Should I use Connection::executeUpdate()?

Tags: doctrine-orm, dbal

I use Doctrine DBAL v2.5.0 and I would like to perform a simple update statement. In the documentation it is written that I should use the method executeUpdate() (http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#executeupdate) for that. But in the source code this method has the annotation @internal. Because of that I am not sure whether this method should be used from non-library code or not. Should I?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to use the `executeUpdate()` method on the doctrine service and not on the entity manager.

`$this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->getConnection()->executeUpdate($query);` gives a warning in my IDE that `executeUpdate()` is @internal.

`$this->container->get('doctrine')->getConnection()->executeUpdate($query);`
or in a controller `$this->getDoctrine()->getConnection()->executeUpdate($query);` does not give any warning.

With other words:
You want to call the executeUpdate() method on

`\Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry` class
instead of the 

`\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` class

P.D. Maybe I should mention that I am using Doctrine in conjunction with Symfony2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But I am not sure about it: `$this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')` gives a `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` object and `$this->container->get('doctrine')` a `Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry` object. But when I call `getConnection()` I get a `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` in both cases, so I end up with the same problem.